# Solve the equation $(m^2-m-2)x=m^2+4m+3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's how I solve it
I think that m is the variable (am I right?).
Then
$$m^2x-mx-2x-m^2-4m-3=0$$
$$m^2(x-1)-m(x+4)-(2x+3)=0$$
$$D=x^2+8x+16+4(x-1)(2x+3)$$
 $$=x^2+8x+16+4(2x^2-2x+3x-3)$$
 $$=9x^2+12x+4$$
 $$=(3x+2)^2$$
$$m=\frac{x+4\pm (3x-2))}{2(x-1)}$$
$$m_1=\frac{4x+2}{2x-2}$$
$$m_2=\frac{-2x+6}{2x-2}$$
Is this right?
I don't know if the tag is right, so please don't be based on it.

Comment: Shouldn't the $m^2$ coefficient be $x-1$ in the second line?

Comment: No: $m$ is a parameter, and you have to solve for $x$. Note the quadratic polynomials in $m$ on the left and right hand sides have a common root.

Comment: Without more context its impossible to know if you are solving for $m$ or $x$ but in most maths textbooks its more common for $x$ to be the variable as pointed out by @Bernard

Comment: We can't tell you what your problem tells you to do.  You got it from the source, we're getting it from you.  I see you've tagged the problem as a diophantine equation.  Are you told that $x$ and $m$ must both be rational?  Or integers?

Comment: I'm voting to close because I think the question is so unclear that it can't be cogently answered (solve for $x$ or solve for $m$, diophantine equation or not, etc.). In fact, it seems a lot of effort has already been wasted trying to answer it.

Comment: @Deepak I did not invent the question. i got it from an exercise book, so it's not my fault it is unclear. That's why I don't think closing this question is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Mike No, the tag may not be correct. That's because I couldn't find a tag to add to this exercise. I speak another language and I don't understand math terms in english correctly. That's why I don't think you should not be based on the tag.

Comment: @prishila OK, maybe I was being a bit harsh. But you must understand how misleading a wrong tag can be. If you can't figure out what the right tag is, better not to tag (not sure if that's an option here, since I've never asked a question on Math.SE). Anyway, I've posted an answer - a little bit of a duplicate since you already have so many answers but it seems no one else has explicitly given $m$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: @prishila do both :) Follow the method I described, express $x$ in terms of $m$ and get the answer for both diophantine equation (as lab bhattacharjee described) and a parameterized one.

Comment: You said you got the problem from an exercise book.  What exactly did the problem ask you to do with the equation?  You seemed to have solved for $m$, but seem to be unclear if that's what you were supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

$m^2-m-2=(m-2)(m+1)$ and $m^2+4m+3=(m+1)(m+3)$

Clearly $m+1=0$ is a solution

Else $(m-2)x=m+3\implies x=\dfrac{m+3}{m-2}=1+\dfrac5{m-2}$

If $x$ is an integer, $(m-2)$ must divide $5$

Answer (score 1):

In case $m$ is not a variable but a parameter, the following method will do.

To solve the following equation for $x$ and every possible $m$ $(x,m \in \mathbb R)$
$$ g(m)x=f(m) $$
you ultimately need to divide both sides by $g(m)$
$$ x = \frac{f(m)}{g(m)}$$

But first, you need to check when $g(m) = 0$. If $m$ is such that $g(m) = 0 = f(m)$ then you get
$$0 *x = 0$$
which is true for every $x$. If $m$ is such that $g(m) = 0 \neq f(m)$ then you get$$0 * x = f(m) \neq 0$$ which is false for every x.

Now that you sure what you get when $g(m)= 0$ you can divide by it. Typically, after the division you can simplify the fraction.

---

In your case, the answer may look like that:

*for $m = -1$, $x \in \mathbb R$*

*for $m = 1$, the equation has no roots*

*for any other $m$, $x=\dfrac{m+3}{m-2}$*

Comment: He wants to solve $m$, NOT $x$...

Comment: @johannesvalks see Bernard's comment to the original post.

Comment: Look and the tag... diophantine-equations

Comment: @johannesvalks you know, maybe you're right. Author is not sure if $m$ is a variable so I still have a suspicion it may be a parameter.  I'll modify my answer so there could be no confusion about what I meant.

Comment: @johannesvalks about the tag diophantine equations, it may not be right. I just chose it because I did not know any other tag to use. The correct exercise is the title and the text of it.

Answer (score 0):

$$(m^2-m-2)x=m^2+4m+3$$
$$(m-2)(m+1)x=(m+1)(m+3)$$
$$m=-1\,\,\,\,\,\text{or}\,\,\,\,\,(m-2)x=(m+3)$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to solve for $m$, the equation can immediately be rewritten as:

$(m-2)(m+1)x = (m+3)(m+1)$

Now it should be obvious that $m=-1$ is a solution as both LHS and RHS become zero (and equal) for this value of $m$.

Now consider the case $m \neq -1$. It is now permissible to divide both sides by $m+1$, simplifying the algebra.

$$(m-2)x = m+3 \implies mx - 2x = m+3 \implies m(x-1) = 2x + 3 \implies m = \frac{2x+3}{x-1}$$

and it should be clear that $x \neq 1$ for this solution to be valid.

Hence your solution set is:
$m=-1$ or $\displaystyle m = \frac{2x+3}{x-1}, (x \neq 1)$